# Magento 2: Customer account create email does not show the images

Tags: magento2, magento2.2

Hello When the user create the account user get the mail in that the images are not showing please help me how can i fix it[image]

Comment: can you show image link?

Comment: Yes @RonakChauhan

Answer (score 0):

Is the website using a BasicAuth, is the website public, are you using a CDN wiht basic Auth or is you SSL certificate expired?

I encountered a similar situation in an UAT environment where the certificate was expired and the emails in gmail weren't showing the images.

You can also check the source of the images by viewing the origin email.

In gmail is located in the top right of the email:

[image: gmail-view-original]